# Efficiently Handling and Scaling WebSockets in Node.js

Tags: node.js, express, websocket

I am working on a rather large IoT project that requires each IoT device to communicate via WebSockets. Each device should only ever have one WebSocket connection open at a time. We also need to post data to WebSocket connections via Express.js POST routes.

Right now I am storing each WebSocket in a `Map` with the IoT device's unique ID as the key and the WebSocket connection as the value. Then when I need to send a message to an IoT device, I call `Map.get()` and use the resulting WebSocket connection to send the message. Here is some example code with that process:

**/storage/websockets.ts**

```js
import WebSocket from 'ws';

const socketConnections: Map<string, WebSocket> = new Map();

export default socketConnections;
```

**/server.ts**

```js
import express from 'express';
import https from 'https';
import fs from 'fs';
import WebSocket from 'ws';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';

import socketConnections from './storage/websockets';

import centralSytemRoutes from './routes/system';

dotenv.config();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

const app = express();
app.use('/centralsystem', centralSytemRoutes);

const server = https.createServer(
  {
    key: fs.readFileSync('./key.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('./cert.pem'),
  },
  app
);
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ server });

wss.on('connection', (ws: WebSocket, req: express.Request) => {
  
  const deviceId = req.url.substr(1);

  socketConnections.set(deviceId, ws);
});

server.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server started on port ${port}`);
});
```

**./routes/system.ts**

```js
import { Router } from 'express';

import socketConnections from '../storage/websockets';

const router = Router();

router.post('/system-message', (req, res, next) => {
  const ws = socketConnections.get(req.body.id);

  ws.send('This is a system message');
});

export default router;
```

Can somebody who has implemented large scale WebSocket solutions offer some insight on whether this will work to store WebSockets and send messages to individual devices in a larger deployment? Right now it works, which is nice. But what about if we scale up to 1,000, 10,000, or even 100,000 devices. If `Map` has to search through 100,000 values every time the system needs to send a message, I feel like there might be a bottleneck building up really fast.

Comment: The Map object should be no issue at all.  They are efficient at very large numbers.  Your issue is probably more about can your server itself handle 100,000 active webSocket connections at once.  Does it have enough bandwidth? Does it have enough CPU to process the packets from that many sockets?  Can the OS itself handle that many simultaneous active sockets?  Will the OS let a single app such as nodejs have access to that many simultaneous active sockets?

Comment: There are certainly special server configurations that have gone much higher than 100,000 webSockets at once, but from what I've read, these are specially configured servers, not something that would normally come with a typical hosting package.

Comment: Thank you! After thinking about it further, I came to the same conclusion. The `ws` package would need to do some sort of array search regardless of how the sockets were stored. As for servers, we are going to have an auto-scaling setup to handle infinite WebSocket connections.